# Can't get Image to float to the top. Need it next to the form in the page

Tags: html, css

I have the image formated how I want, I just can't get it to float to the top so it looks nice next to the form I made. I have tried making a div and having that float up to no avail. Help?

```css
header {
  background-color: #030303;
  color: #ffffff;
  height: 60px;
  text-align: left;
  padding-top: 30px;
  padding-left: 3em;
  background-image: url("assets/dndlogo.jpg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: right;
}

#dndlogo {
  float: right;
  height: 50px;
}

header h1 {
  font-family: Georgia, "Times New Roman", Serif;
  margin-top: 0px;
  font-size: 3em;
  letter-spacing: 0.25em;
}

#schedulebox {
  float: left;
  height: 750px;
  width: 15%;
  float: left;
  background-color: #bd0202;
  text-align: center;
}

#homecontent {
  height: 750px;
  width: 84.3%;
  float: left;
  background-color: #030303;
  color: white;
}

nav {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #030303;
  font-family: Arial;
  float: top;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

nav li {
  float: left;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 15px 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  list-style-type: none;
  color: white;
  height: 15px;
}


/*nav li:hover{
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 15px;
    transition: 0.5s;
    color: black;
}*/

nav ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  padding-left: 0;
}

footer {
  background-color: #030303;
  float: bottom;
  color: white;
}

#schedulebox h1 {
  border-bottom: solid;
  padding-top: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

html {
  background-color: #030303;
}

button {
  background-color: #030303;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  height: 27px;
}

button:hover {
  background-color: white;
  color: #030303;
  border-radius: 5px;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

main {
  border: white solid;
  border-radius: 10px;
  order-radius: 10px;
}

#wrapper {
  padding: 20px;
}

#schedulebox {
  border-right: white solid;
}

#dragonpic {
  width: 1556.5px;
  height: auto;
}

#homecontent2 {
  border: solid white;
}

.clearfix::after {
  content: "";
  clear: both;
  display: table;
}

#homecontent h2,
#homecontent h3 {
  padding-left: 10px;
}

#resourcescontent {
  color: white;
  padding-left: 10px;
}

a img:visited {
  border: black;
}

a img:hover {
  border: white solid;
  border-width: thin;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

a.button {
  -webkit-appearance: button;
  -moz-appearance: button;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  height: 20px;
  padding: 5px;
  font-size: 20px;
}

a.button:hover {
  background-color: white;
  color: #030303;
  transition: 0.3s;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

#beyondlogo {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 50%;
  display: block;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

#resourcescontent p,
#resourcescontent h2 {
  text-align: center;
}

form {
  color: white;
}

label {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  text-align: right;
  width: 120px;
  padding-right: 1em;
}

input,
textarea {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

#joiningcontent h2 {
  color: white;
  padding-left: 20px;
  width: 20%;
  text-align: center;
}

#joiningpic {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-bottom: auto;
  width: 50%;
  display: block;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

#joiningcontent {}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <header>
    <h1>Dungeons and Dragons: WCTC</h1>
  </header>
  <main class="clearfix">
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="index.html" class="button">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="resources.html" class="button">Resources</a></li>
        <li><a href="joining.html" class="button">Join Us!</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    <div id="joiningcontent">
      <h2>If you wish to join, provide us with some information so we can contact you!</h2>
      <form>
        <label for="FirstName">First Name:</label>
        <input type="text" id="FirstName" name="FName" required>
        <label for="LastName">Last Name:</label>
        <input type="text" id="LastName" name="LName" required>
        <label for="emailboi">Email:</label>
        <input type="email" id="emailboi" name="Email" required>
        <label for="GuestOrMember">Are you signing up as a Guest?</label>
        <input id="GuestOrMember" type="checkbox">
        <button type="submit" value="submit">Submit</button>
      </form>
      <img src="assets/signuppic.png" id="joiningpic">
    </div>
  </main>
</div>
```

I'm still a little lost on what to do and I'm fairly new to web development so I appologize for any ameteur mistakes made.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For both the img and the form you need to:

```
float: left;
display: inline;
```

This is due to the form being a block level element so you need to float both left and set them to be inline, rather than block. If you put img before form then it will be on the left of the form, put it after the form and it will be on the right of the form.

Be aware that if the image and form do not fit within the width of the browser window then they will wrap and one will be below the other, whichever way round you have them.

https://jsfiddle.net/bryanwadd/o1da8buw/

Comment: Ok this gets me really close. The form now is just stuck on the bottom.

Comment: @Glitch it may just be the width: 50% on your image on a narrow screen. Inline floats will wrap on a narrow screen.

Comment: @Glitch I updated the jsfiddle to remove the width: 50% from the image.

Comment: Thank you so much! Its greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

For correct working `float`, the floated element should be the first. Just move `img` as a first element in parent, like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Sign Up</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
    <header>
        <h1>Dungeons and Dragons: WCTC</h1>
    </header>
    <main class="clearfix">
        <nav><ul><li><a href="index.html" class="button">Home</a></li>  <li><a href="resources.html" class="button">Resources</a></li>  <li><a href="joining.html" class="button">Join Us!</a></li></ul></nav>
        <div id="joiningcontent">
          <img src="assets/signuppic.png" id="joiningpic">
          <h2>If you wish to join, provide us with some information so we can contact you!</h2>
          <form>
            <label for="FirstName">First Name:</label>
            <input type="text" id="FirstName" name="FName" required>
            <label for="LastName">Last Name:</label>
            <input type="text" id="LastName" name="LName" required>
            <label for="emailboi">Email:</label>
            <input type="email" id="emailboi" name="Email" required>
            <label for="GuestOrMember">Are you signing up as a Guest?</label>
            <input id="GuestOrMember" type="checkbox">
            <button type="submit" value="submit">Submit</button>
        </form>

        </div>
    </main>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

**UPDATED2**

```css
header{
        background-color: #030303;
        color:#ffffff;
        height: 60px;
        text-align: left;
        padding-top: 30px;
        padding-left: 3em;
        background-image: url("assets/dndlogo.jpg");
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position: right;
    }
    
    #dndlogo{
        float: right;
        height: 50px;
    }
    
    header h1{
        font-family: Georgia, "Times New Roman", Serif;
        margin-top: 0px;
        font-size: 3em;
        letter-spacing: 0.25em;
    }
    
    #schedulebox{
        float: left;
        height: 750px;
        width: 15%;
        float: left;
        background-color: #bd0202;
        text-align: center;
    }
    
    #homecontent{
        height: 750px;
        width: 84.3%;
        float: left;
        background-color: #030303;
        color: white;
    }
    
    nav {
        overflow: hidden;
        background-color: #030303;
        font-family: Arial;
        float: top;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        border-radius: 10px;
    }
    
    nav li{
        float: left;
        font-size: 20px;
        color: black;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 15px 20px;
        text-decoration: none;
        list-style-type: none;
        color: white;
        height: 15px;
    }
    
    /*nav li:hover{
        background-color: white;
        border-radius: 15px;
        transition: 0.5s;
        color: black;
    }*/
    
    nav ul{
        margin: 0;
        padding-bottom: 10px;
        padding-left: 0;
    }
    
    footer{
        background-color: #030303;
        float: bottom;
        color: white;
    
    }
    
    #schedulebox h1{
        border-bottom: solid;
        padding-top: 0;
        margin: 0;
    }
    
    html{
        background-color: #030303;
    }
    
    button{
        background-color: #030303;
        border: none;
        color: white;
        font-size: 20px;
        height: 27px;
    }
    
    button:hover{
        background-color: white;
        color: #030303;
        border-radius: 5px;
        transition: 0.5s;
    }
    
    main{
        border: white solid;
        border-radius: 10px;
        order-radius: 10px;
    }
    
    #wrapper{
        padding: 20px;
    }
    
    #schedulebox{
        border-right: white solid;
    }
    
    #dragonpic{
        width: 1556.5px;
        height: auto;
    }
    
    #homecontent2{
        border: solid white;
    }
    
    .clearfix::after {
        content: "";
        clear: both;
        display: table;
    }
    
    #homecontent h2, #homecontent h3{
        padding-left: 10px;
    }
    
    #resourcescontent{
        color: white;
        padding-left: 10px;
    }
    
    a img:visited{
        border: black;
    }
    
    a img:hover{
        border: white solid;
        border-width: thin;
        transition: 0.3s;
    }
    
    a.button {
        -webkit-appearance: button;
        -moz-appearance: button;
        border: none;
        color: white;
        text-decoration: none;
        height: 20px;
        padding: 5px;
        font-size: 20px;
    }
    
    a.button:hover{
        background-color: white;
        color: #030303;
        transition: 0.3s;
        border-radius: 5px;
    }
    
    #beyondlogo{
       margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
        width: 50%;
        display: block;
        border-radius: 10px;
    }
    
    #resourcescontent p, #resourcescontent h2{
        text-align: center;
    }
    
    form{
        color: white;
        display: inline-block;
        vertical-align: top;
        max-width: 40%;
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    
    label{
        float: left;
        display: block;
        text-align: right;
        width: 120px;
        padding-right: 1em;
    }
    
    input, textarea{
        display: block;
        margin-bottom: 20px;
    
    }
    
    #joiningcontent h2{
        color: white;
        padding-left: 20px;
        width: 20%;
        text-align: center;
    }
    
    #joiningpic{
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-bottom: auto;
        width: 50%;
        border-radius: 10px;
        display: inline-block;
        vertical-align: top;
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    
    #joiningcontent{
    
    }
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
    <header>
        <h1>Dungeons and Dragons: WCTC</h1>
    </header>
    <main class="clearfix">
        <nav><ul><li><a href="index.html" class="button">Home</a></li>  <li><a href="resources.html" class="button">Resources</a></li>  <li><a href="joining.html" class="button">Join Us!</a></li></ul></nav>
        <div id="joiningcontent">
          
        <h2>If you wish to join, provide us with some information so we can contact you!</h2>
        
        <form>
            <label for="FirstName">First Name:</label>
            <input type="text" id="FirstName" name="FName" required>
            <label for="LastName">Last Name:</label>
            <input type="text" id="LastName" name="LName" required>
            <label for="emailboi">Email:</label>
            <input type="email" id="emailboi" name="Email" required>
            <label for="GuestOrMember">Are you signing up as a Guest?</label>
            <input id="GuestOrMember" type="checkbox">
            <button type="submit" value="submit">Submit</button>
        </form>
        
        <img src="assets/signuppic.png" id="joiningpic">
            
        </div>
    </main>
</div>
```

Comment: Ok I changed it, and now the form is on the bottom. I am trying to get these to be on the same level.

Comment: do you have live example? or just example of the image?

Comment: Updated the answer. If i understood you correctly. Look please

Comment: Did not quite work. I will try uploading an image in imgur for you. 
https://imgur.com/a/gfl2gMc

Comment: Updated, please look.

Comment: Not quite. I added some padding and got it to move over to the right, I just need to get it to move up now. https://imgur.com/a/vQ1hqrO

Comment: May be try to use `box-sizing: border-box;`when you using `padding` in the same element. Or  can make a picture, what exact place so you what the picture to be? Added  `box-sizing: border-box;` to answer